# How to return a string that contains specific match?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to return a string that exactly matches: "Item1_20". I have 1 as the Item_no and 20 as the item_size.

```
var str = ["Item1_20","Item2_20","Item3_30"....];
var Item_no = 1;  
var Item_size = 20;
for (var i=0; i<str.length; i++)
{
var match = str.match(/Item_no + '_' + Item_size/g);
}
```

So match should be returned only if it exactly matches "Item1_20".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
var match = (str[i] == "Item"+Item_no+"_"+Item_size);
```

No real need to use regex if you want an exact match. Be careful that str is the array, str[i] is the string

Answer (score 1):

You should be using indexOf

```
str.indexOf(Item_no + '_' + Item_size)
```

so if you get `-1`, there is no match.

If you want to use a regular expression, that is not how you build one. You would do it with [`new RegExp(Item_no + '_' + Item_size,"g")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) and your loop is NOT comparing each index.

Answer (score 0):

`Array.indexOf(string)` returns the index of `string` in the array, `-1` if not found
`index > -1` returns true if `string` was found in `Array`.

```
var match = str.indexOf('Item' + Item_no + '_' + Item_size) > -1;
```

And here is a demo:

```js
var str = ["Item1_20","Item2_20","Item3_30"];
var Item_no = 1;  
var Item_size = 20;
var item_index = str.indexOf('Item' + Item_no + '_' + Item_size);
var match = item_index > -1;
alert( 'Found: ' + item_index + '\nIndex: ' + match );
```